# pyqt Multiple objects share context menu

Tags: python, pyqt5, contextmenu

So I'm relatively new to qt and fairly seasoned with python.
However, I have an instance where I want multiple widgets (in this case labels) to share the same custom context menu but I need to get access to the widget's information.

When I use `setContextMenuPolicy` and `customContextMenuRequested.connect` on each label I only get information for the first label despite accessing the context menu with the second label.

Below is a stripped down version of what I'm working with:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenu, QLabel
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "PyQt5 Context Menu"
        self.top = 200
        self.left = 500
        self.width = 200
        self.height = 100
        self.InitWindow()

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.firstLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.firstLabel.setText("Meep!")
        self.firstLabel.setObjectName("firstLabel")
        self.firstLabel.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(252, 233, 79);")

        self.firstLabel.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.firstLabel.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.customMenuEvent)

        self.firstLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0,0,50,30))


        self.secondLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.secondLabel.setText("Peem!")
        self.secondLabel.setObjectName("secondLabel")
        self.secondLabel.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(79,233, 252);")

        self.secondLabel.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.secondLabel.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.customMenuEvent)

        self.secondLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80,40,50,30))

        print("FIRST:", self.firstLabel)
        print("SECOND:", self.secondLabel)

        self.show()

    def customMenuEvent(self, eventPosition):
        child = self.childAt(eventPosition)
        print(child)
        contextMenu = QMenu(self)
        getText = contextMenu.addAction("Text")
        getName = contextMenu.addAction("Name")
        quitAct = contextMenu.addAction("Quit")
        action = contextMenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(eventPosition))

        if action == getText:
            print(child.text())

        if action == getName:
            print(child.objectName())

        if action == quitAct:
            self.close()



App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: tip: if you don't have qt5 designer installed I recommend doing that. It lets you build a simple GUI in minutes with everything in place and context. Alternative fork from qt is PySide.

Comment: Thanks, I do actually have and use Qt5 designer but I threw this together as a proof of concept (in ineptitude).

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation about the [`customContextMenuRequested(pos)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) signal:

> The position pos is the position of the context menu event that the widget receives

This means that you will always receive the mouse position *relative to the widget that fires the signal*.

You're using `QWidget.childAt()`, which is relative to the parent geometry, but since the provided position is relative to the child widget, you'll always end up with coordinates that are relative to the top left corner of the parent.

This becomes clear if you try to set the geometry of the first widget in a position that's not the top left corner: even if you right-click on the first widget, you'll see that the menu will *not* appear where you clicked. If you look closely, you'll also see that the menu appears exactly at the position you clicked, based on the coordinates of the parent top left corner.

For the sake of simplicity, an easy solution would be to map the coordinates from the "[`sender`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender)" (which is the object that fired the last signal the receiver has received) to its parent:

```
    def customMenuEvent(self, eventPosition):
        child = self.childAt(self.sender().mapTo(self, eventPosition))
        contextMenu = QMenu(self)
        getText = contextMenu.addAction("Text")
        getName = contextMenu.addAction("Name")
        quitAct = contextMenu.addAction("Quit")

        # note that the mapToGlobal is referred to the child!
        action = contextMenu.exec_(child.mapToGlobal(eventPosition))
        # ...
```

But be aware that this could lead to some inconsistency, especially when dealing with multithreading (as, theoretically, another thread could have fired another signal *between* the right click event *and* the moment the receiver actually receives it).

There are various different approaches to avoid that, but IT mostly depends on how you are going to structure your program.

For example, you could use a lambda to add an argument that helps to identify the source from which the event has been sent:

```
        self.firstLabel.customContextMenuRequested.connect(
            lambda pos, child=self.firstLabel: self.customMenuEvent(pos, child))
        # ...

    def customMenuEvent(self, eventPosition, child):
        # ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Multithreading isn't an issue for me at the moment so the first example worked great.
I've still got a long way to go with Qt!

Comment: You're welcome! Keep in mind, though, that `self.sender()` should always be used with care and consciously ([Qt docs warn](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) about that), and the second approach, while it might seem a bit more complex, is preferred and is more coherent, since the child argument will always be explicit.